# Script Execution at user logout (non root user)

Tags: scripts, root, logout

I am in my university labs running ubuntu 12.10 with unity and I don't have root privilleges. I need to run a script at logout. Is this possible?

Note: this is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102061/root-script-execution-at-non-root-user-login-logout), however the answers given are quite cryptic and no specific directions are given.

Comment: Depends on whether it's a graphical login, or "command-line" login

Comment: It's a graphical login.

Comment: I guess You can write a log-out script which runs what You want, and then logs out with `gnome-session-quit` or something like that.

Comment: @adobe Hmm.. Thanks, that sounds like a good workaround in my case. It's weird though that a non-privilleged user does not seem to have a straightforward way to deal with this situation.. Btw I do not seem to be able to vote up, probably due to low rep.

Comment: @geo909: why study yet another system -- when a simple bash script solves it? Let me know if You'll be in trobles with bash script.

Comment: @adobe It's a good solution and I'll very happily go with it. Just not the most elegant :) I have some scripts that I not only use when logout so I'll have to have two versions, one that logs out and one which is not.. So I'll have to also have different shortcuts or keyboard bindings for those. Plus my force of habit is to log out using the button on the upper bar; I cannot add a new button or something to use my script, I cannot configure anythig in the labs..

Comment: No need for two scripts: make one script which takes a parameter. No need for two buttons: for logout make the same button with shift key. I think it is possible to bind to upper bar also.

Comment: Related, for Gnome: [How can I run a script during GNOME logout if I don't have admin privileges?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49333/how-can-i-run-a-script-during-gnome-logout-if-i-dont-have-admin-privileges)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the step by step procedure of `gnome_save_yourself` method. Let's do a test.

1. Save following code as `~/Desktop/execute_script_on_shutdown.sh`    (From http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/gnome-run-script-on-logout-724453/#post3560301)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Author: Seamus Phelan

#This program runs a custom command/script just before gnome shuts 
#down.  This is done the same way that gedit does it (listening for 
#the 'save-yourself' event).  This is different to placing scipts 
#in /etc/rc#.d/ as the script will be run before gnome exits.
#If the custom script/command fails with a non-zero return code, a 
#popup dialog box will appear offering the chance to cancel logout
#
#Usage: 1 - change the command in the 'subprocess.call' in 
#           function 'session_save_yourself' below to be what ever
#           you want to run at logout.
#       2 - Run this program at every gnome login (add via menu System 
#           -> Preferences -> Session)
# 
#

import sys
import subprocess
import datetime

import gnome
import gnome.ui
import gtk


class Namespace: pass
ns = Namespace()
ns.dialog = None


def main():
    prog = gnome.init ("gnome_save_yourself", "1.0", gnome.libgnome_module_info_get(), sys.argv, [])
    client = gnome.ui.master_client()
    #set up call back for when 'logout'/'Shutdown' button pressed
    client.connect("save-yourself", session_save_yourself)
    client.connect("shutdown-cancelled", shutdown_cancelled)


def session_save_yourself( *args):
        #Lets try to unmount all truecrypt volumes
        
        
    #execute shutdowwn script
    #########################################################################################
    retcode = subprocess.call("bash /home/totti/Desktop/shutdown_script.sh", shell=True)
    ##########################################################################################
    if retcode != 0:
        #command failed  
        show_error_dialog()
    return True

def shutdown_cancelled( *args):
    if ns.dialog != None:
        ns.dialog.destroy()
    return True


def show_error_dialog():
    ns.dialog = gtk.Dialog("There was a problem running your pre-shutdown script",
                           None,
                           gtk.DIALOG_MODAL | gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                           ("There was a problem running your pre-shutdown script - continue logout", gtk.RESPONSE_ACCEPT))
    if ns.test_mode == True:
        response = ns.dialog.run()
        ns.dialog.destroy()
    else:
        #when in shutdown mode gnome will only allow you to open a window using master_client().save_any_dialog()
        #It also adds the 'Cancel logout' button
        gnome.ui.master_client().save_any_dialog(ns.dialog)



#Find out if we are in test mode???
if len(sys.argv) >=2 and sys.argv[1] == "test":
    ns.test_mode = True
else:
    ns.test_mode = False

if ns.test_mode == True:
    main()
    session_save_yourself()
else:
    main()
    gtk.main()
```

2. Make it executable:

   ```
    chmod +x ~/Desktop/execute_script_on_shutdown.sh
   ```
3. Save the following as `~/Desktop/shutdown_script.sh`

   ```
    #!/usr/bin/bash
    touch ~/Desktop/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
   ```
4. Execute the main script

   ```
    bash ~/Desktop/execute_script_on_shutdown.sh
   ```

Now you feel the script wait for something

5. Log Out or shutdown your OS (Ubuntu)
6. Log in
7. Check for a file named `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` on your desktop.

   ```
    ls -l ~/Desktop/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
   ```

If you see the file everything OK. Now you can edit the `shutdown_script.sh` to suit your need. Also remember to execute the `execute_script_on_shutdown.sh` on login (or make it auto executable on startup).

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47861505/0-published/execute_script_on_shutdown.sh

Comment: Unfortunately I'll be off campus for a while and I don't have access to a gnome desktop. If this is tested and works, I can accept it as the answer, though..

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Does this work with Unity?

Comment: Tested successfully on Ubuntu 12.10, with unity

Comment: Can this be made to work using Cinnamon (i.e. Linux Mint 21)?