# Is it possible to run an OPENGL program via a daemon?

Tags: upstart, services, opengl

My main question is: Is it possible to run an OPENGL program via a daemon (upstart script)? The program displays a window on the screen.

More details: I have an opengl program (done with openframeworks, C++) that i want to run with a daemon.

Manually i start my program in the terminal like this:

```
planeviz@planeviz:~/src/of/apps/myApps/planeEtoiles/bin$ ./planeEtoiles
```

Now i created an upstart script (/etc/init/myapp.conf), that should start the program when the computer boots, and make sure to restart it in case of crashes.

```
# job file
description "myapp"
author "eva"

# When to start the service
start on startup
start on runlevel [2345]

# When to stop the service
stop on runlevel [016]

# Automatically restart process if crashed
respawn

# Start the process
script
    sudo /home/planeviz/src/of/apps/myApps/planeEtoiles/bin/planeEtoiles
end script
```

Then i try to start the daemon via

```
sudo service myapp start
```

My application doesn't open. dmesg tell me:

```
planeviz@planeviz:/etc/init$ dmesg | grep "init:"
[ 5282.003496] init: myapp main process (8008) terminated with status 139
```

Termination status 139 seems to hint at a segmentation fault. Looking at the output of my program in the upstart log, i see the last error to be related to the creation of the opengl window.

```
planeviz@planeviz:/etc/init$ sudo tail /var/log/upstart/planeetoiles.log
....
[ error ] ofAppGLFWWindow: couldn't init GLFW
```

This makes me wonder if its even possible to run OPENGL programs with upstart, or if it is only meant to work with background processes?

Comment: Do you want the program to be displayed on your desktop? Or is it only using OpenGL to perform rendering and saving the output to a file? If the latter, does it rely on the GPU?

Comment: Yes, i want it to display a window on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upstart is designed for system services. While you can (at least with recent versions) use it to monitor a command that runs during a user session, it's clumsy.

With Upstart, if you want to run a service that displays a GUI window, that service can only run while you're logged in. Rather than start and stop based on runlevels, you need to start and stop based on GUI login and logout events.

```
start on desktop-session-start
stop on desktop-shutdown
```

You also need the service to be able to reach your display. GUI applications use the `DISPLAY` environment variable to determine where to display. Under normal circumstances, your GUI session will be the display called `:0`.

```
env DISPLAY=:0
```

The application also needs to obtain permission to access the display. This permission takes the form of a “cookie” (a password) which is automatically generated when your GUI session starts and stored in the file `.Xauthority` in your home directory (or another file indicated by the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable, depending on your display manager). If your display manager uses `~/.Xauthority` and you run the service as your user (which you should do anyway), you don't need to set `XAUTHORITY`. For more details, see [Can I launch a graphical program on another user's desktop as root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root/1600#1600) and [Open a window on a remote X display (why “Cannot open display”)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126)

```
setuid evsc
```

---

Instead of Upstart, you can use a supervision tool that only does supervision and not system service management. [Ensure a process is always running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/881/ensure-a-process-is-always-running) lists several possibilities. Let's use [`supervise`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/supervise.8.html) from [daemontools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/daemontools). Create a directory somewhere, e.g. `~/.planeEtoiles`. In this directory, create an executable called `run` which is the application you want to keep running:

```
mkdir ~/.planeEtoiles
ln -s /home/planeviz/src/of/apps/myApps/planeEtoiles/bin/planeEtoiles ~/.planeEtoiles/run
```

Add the command `supervise ~/.planeEtoiles` to the [applications automatically started at login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login). To stop the service, use the [`svc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/svc.8.html) command:

```
svc -t -x ~/.planeEtoiles
```

The last piece of the puzzle is running that `svc` command on logout. This feature seems to be missing, or if not it's very poorly documented. If you're using GDM, there's a workaround which is to run from [`/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2745/how-to-run-a-script-during-gnome-log-out), but that file runs command as root, which is not a good solution, and doesn't apply to Lightdm. Monitor [Script Execution at user logout (non root user)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317489/script-execution-at-user-logout-non-root-user) and [How can I run a script during GNOME logout if I don't have admin privileges?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49333/how-can-i-run-a-script-during-gnome-logout-if-i-dont-have-admin-privileges) for solutions.

Comment: i went with the 'supervise' solution, and it's doing exactly what i want it to do! thanks!